# Can I use existing Google analytics/Search Console for SSL based site?

Tags: google-analytics, google-search-console, https

I am planning to change hosting provider(From Site5 to Namecheap) and also will be using SSL. My site(WordPress) is 5+ years old and indexed. My question is, can I just change `http://example.com` to `https://example.com` and not lose any traffic and another thing in the existing Search Console Property and Analytics? if yes, what changes will I need to make?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can just change `http://example.com` to `https://example.com` but need to make sure that make 301 redirect all links from `http://` to `https://` version.

Also, you need to create new `https://` version Search Console Property and resubmit the sitemap again.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to get back due to other commitments. So what would happen with my indexed pages and keywords if I create a new property?

Comment: When you do the 301 redirect from http:// to https:// version and create a new property; your all indexed pages will change from http:// to https:// on the google search result, and your new property will collect the data. And your keyword ranking data will remain same if do the task properly. :)